# How to agree with an "I have never..." statement?

Tags: usage

My colleague who is native English speaker said "I have never been to Croatia before"

Is it correct to say: "neither have I"?

My tutor said I should use "neither" only with contractions like

> "I don't like broccoli."
>   "Neither do I".

And "I have never been there" is I think affirmative because there's no contraction...

Comment: Um, if your tutor said you can only use "neither" to agree with sentences containing contractions, I think you need a new tutor.

Comment: @MissMonicaE A 100%. What tutor says such a thing?

Comment: I'd like to hear the actual wording the tutor used before I jump to a conclusion. And 'contraction' morphs into 'contradiction' later; I think misrepresentation has to be involved here.

Comment: It was my mistake sorry for that. I ment of course "contractions"

Answer (score 1):

You have two wonderful choices:

- Me neither
- Neither have I

And more:

- Nor have I

Comment: Is ***Me too*** a choice for affirmative sentences? If so what are some equevalents to "me too"?

Comment: @GamalThomas **"Me too"** is a choice for an affirmative sentence as well as **"So do (am, did) I"**, **"And me"** and **"Me also"**

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is indeed correct to reply to your colleague's statement with "Neither have I".

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain me why? My tutor said I should use "neither" only with contradictions like "I don't like broccoli. Neither do i". And following statement "I have never been there" is I think affirmative

Comment: @Tomas: *I have never been to Croatia before* is not an affirmative sentence; it's a negative one. And your reply *Neither have I* is also a negative sentence and it's acceptable. **Neither** is used to talk about two or more negative ideas in a related sense; not to talk about contradictions. You can also use *I haven't either* or *Nor have I* in place of *Neither have I*.